# What could cause this terminal rendering difference?

Tags: linux, terminal, docker

I have to ubuntu 22.04:

- one is Azure, created from Canonical image
- another is docker created from docker hub Canonical official image. **This is the deployment which exhibits the issue**

I've installed mc to both, and on the docker version shows incorrect characters on the border special characters.
It seems something codepage/language setting difference but...

What is identical in the two (so changing anything related probably is not the solutions)

- I've created two **identical** mobaxterm session definition (with duplicate) and I've changed nothing else, just the IP address. (so this is not about the SSH client setting
- I've copied the working .bashrc to the not working, then created a new SSH session.

In general it seems to be this is nothing to do with the SSH client (and its setting) because if I simply get a prompt with `docker exec -it <containername> bash` **the issue is there**

Of course I could live without mc but the issue is not about mc, and I do not want a hidden, not understood configuration issue in my systems.

Further diagostics, thx for the comment:

```
$ printf '\xc2\xab\n' # on both terminals
«

$ locale # on bad bad
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

$ locale # on good
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale charmap # on bad
ANSI_X3.4-1968

$ locale charmap # on good
UTF-8

~$ dpkg -l | grep ncurses # on bad
ii  libncurses6:amd64                    6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncursesw6:amd64                   6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  ncurses-base                         6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          all          basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin                          6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        terminal-related programs and man pages
ii  ncurses-term                         6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          all          additional terminal type definitions

gabor@vm-wp-01:~$ dpkg -l | grep ncurses # on good
ii  libncurses6:amd64                      6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncursesw6:amd64                     6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  ncurses-base                           6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          all          basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin                            6.3-2ubuntu0.1                          amd64        terminal-related programs and man pages
```

[image: docker deployment]

[image: Azure deployment]

Comment: What does `printf '\xc2\xab\n'` output on the bad terminal? What does `locale` output on both, as well as `locale charmap`... and maybe `dpkg -l | grep ncurses`?

Comment: many thx for the diagnostics, see in the edited question

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with `mc`'s `slang` build (I haven't tried its `ncurses` build), combined with a skin that defines to use double lines, combined with the C (a.k.a. POSIX) locale or lack of proper locale definitions. Could be an issue in `mc` or `slang`, I don't know. Anyway, it's pointless to dig into these details. Use UTF-8, period. Make sure your locale variables are set to `C.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8` or similar. I leave it up to you to figure out why it's not set this way and how to set them on the buggy machine, I can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: @egmont, thx for the detais. Indeed, the single line border characters are working the double lines not, which is strange in its own right. Anyway,  having no experience with the locale/language, I am wondering where are those set/configured system wide. One for sure, not in .bashrc, because that are identical on both hosts...

Comment: Look at `/etc/locale.conf`, also note, as per that file, that you should run `update-locales` which also generates the actual locale definitios (i.e., does more than just editing that file, so manually editing the file might not be enough). If this doesn't help then there are more details here that I'm not familiar with, so in that case I recommend you to ask another question focusing on docker vs. locales, not mc.

Comment: neither `/etc/locale.conf` file neither `update-locales` executable are on neither hosts